# How to set marker image from URL in Here Map Sdk

Tags: java, android, here-api

I am setting a marker (there will be more from server) on a map using here map SDK 
SDK provides various methods to set marker image from drawable, local string, from files and from assets but there is no method to a laod image from URL, I tried first converting image from URL to bitmap then I used SDK method setBitmap but it gives me an error "Provided image is invalid"
could you please help me in this matter

Tried setting image as a bitmap but gives error Provided image is invalid

```
private class AsyncTaskLoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) url.getContent());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i(">>stat", "doInBackground: ");
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            try {
                myImage.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(CustomerHomeDashboardActivity.this, "Cannot"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }`
```

Expected result should be marker added to map 
as I have tested this function for other URL image to Drawable and it worked

below is the method that I am using to convert the image URL from server to Bitmap and then setting it as `mImage.setBitmap(CONVERTED_BITMAP)` image received in URL from server can be either JPEG or PNG but no matter what format I use every time I get same error "Provided image is invalid"

```
com.here.android.mpa.common.Image myImage;

 private class AsyncTaskLoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) url.getContent());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(">>stat", "doInBackground: ");
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention the format of the image have in order to tell whether SDK supports that or not.
Secondly, we do not provide Marker.setUrl(...) method as this should not be part of SDK functionality, there are tons of libs that can load image from the server and decode it into bitmap.

Comment: I have updated my question, added the function that I am using to convert the URL to bitmap then using HERE-SDK method `Image.setBitmap(BITMAP)`

Comment: Please provide the image itself(e.g. link to it), so we will investigate.

Comment: [Marker Image](https://www.navizinhanca.com/public/images/categoryimage/1559807417.Baba-a-noite.png) this is the link to marker icon I want to show on map

Comment: It seems that you have to create `new Image(bitmap)` and reset it to `MapMarker` every time you want to change icon for marker.

Comment: @NazarK Yes I create new image every time and then setting `newImage.setBitmap(bitmap)` and insert that image to a pojo class so I think you are trying to say my image is going overriden that is why I am not seeing any marker on map? No I create new Image every time `myImage = new com.here.android.mpa.common.Image();` the I set bitmap but evey time I get error "Provided image not valid" here-api have some issues I guess because same url to Bitmap decode functions works If try to setBitmap on some other android sdk ImageView

Comment: You will have to post all the code and share link to it. so I we can investigate that.